# Once Free Shipping method show then hide other charge shipping method but keep store pick

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3

I have multiple shipping methods,
1- Custom Shipping Method with Charge at £100
2- Store pick up - Free after £100
3- Free Shipping

So When Free Shipping method reaches cart value 100 then hide Custom shipping method. But at the time Store pickup also show.

I was tried with plugin but in that case, its hide all shipping method as soon as free shipping condition meet.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use around plugin `aroundCollectCarrierRates`

```
class HideShipping {

public function aroundCollectCarrierRates(
    \Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping $subject,
    \Closure $proceed,
    $carrierCode,
    $request
) {

    // Hide all shipping methods except free shipping method
    if ($carrierCode == 'freeshipping') {
        return false;
    } 

    $result = $proceed($carrierCode, $request);
    return $result;
}
```

}

In this example, `freeshipping` will be hidden. You can write your own logic and even use your custom carrier codes to show/hide shipping methods as you need to.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! It's working for me.

Comment: Then accept the answer please so that it helps others too.